# Data is not shown in SqlLite in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing the app that storing data in the Database in Windows phone8 using SqlLite. The data is inserted successfully. But when I go and saw from Mozila->SQL Lite Manager, the data is not shown. Is it possible to read the data?

Comment: are you sure that while inserting date you are not getting any exception? please let me know, may be I can help you.

Comment: No,there is no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not yet possible to read data from Mozila->SQLite Manager in WP8. If you want to see what data is stored in your database, execute a query in app. For more information follow [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/1ad3daec-12e6-4647-bf81-ffc50fd535bb/how-can-we-find-dbcreated-sqlite-database-file-file-in-windows-phone-8-emulator?forum=wpdevelop)